# Overpass Turbo parse and static error

Tags: overpass-turbo

I have written the following code filter out some power data in overpass turbo.

```
[out:json][timeout:1000];
//fetch area "Tokyo" to search in
{{gecodeArea:Tokyo}}->.searchArea;
//gather results
(
  // query part for: "power=tower"
  node["power"="tower"](area.searchArea);
  //query part for: "power=line"
  way["power"="line"](area.searchArea);
  // query part for"power=substation"
  node["power"="substation"](area.searchArea);
);

//print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

However I get the following 2 errors,

```
Error: line 8: parse error: Unknown type "->"

Error: line 8: static error: For the attribute "type" of the element "query" the only allowed values are "node", "way", "relation", "nwr", "nw", "wr", "nr", or "area".
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Note to create `->` symbol I am using the minus sign and greater than sign from the keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just had a typo - gecodeArea  >> ge**o**codeArea The rest of the query is fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrbJS.jpg

```
[out:json][timeout:1000];
//fetch area "Tokyo" to search in
{{geocodeArea:Tokyo}}->.searchArea;
//gather results
(
  // query part for: "power=tower"
  node["power"="tower"](area.searchArea);
  //query part for: "power=line"
  way["power"="line"](area.searchArea);
  // query part for"power=substation"
  node["power"="substation"](area.searchArea);
);

//print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```